# How optimal is bicycle design?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life, estimation

Forgive any imprecision in this question but I've always wondered why the design of a bike has not been improved over the last 100+ years. I was reminded of this following the new [speed record](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2019/aug/18/british-man-sets-new-cycling-speed-record-of-more-than-174mph).

I don't know the best way to measure efficiency as clearly there's a difference between optimising for max speed, min effort/distance on the flat or for climbing ability, so I welcome a broad range of answers. Obviously friction and mass are major considerations.

Clearly we can say that, given maintained and relatively roads/pavements, a bike is a much more efficient way of travelling that walking on foot. I'm not interested in UCI rules rather theoretical limits.

But if you look at the changes between the first bikes and contemporary frame/wheel layouts there's clearly more and less "optimal" options. Or compare them to other means of human-powered transport (helicopters, scooters, in-line skates, hand bikes, etc.). Or look at the history of aviation (helicopter/flapping to bi-plane to swept wing to bidirectional) or hull design (monohull to multihull to SWATH).

Why have there been no major changes to the *design* of a pedal bike? How could this design be optimised further?

Is there really nothing better than two circular wheels and two cogs?

Comment: In order to have any sort of theoretical limit, there needs to be a constraint on how much we can change the existing bicycle design, and how many of the environmental factors we can take away. For example, if I'm allowed to call a rigid cube sliding frictionlessly along the ground in a vacuum a "bicycle", then there isn't any meaningful theoretical limit on the efficiency - no energy is wasted at all in that case. So what makes a bicycle a bicycle, and what conditions should we assume that we're operating in?

Comment: "Welcoming a broad range of answers" makes this off topic. We expect it to be clear what answers are correct and which are incorrect.

Comment: Bicycles have made many changes in the last 100 years, but no matter what, it comes to muscle against air resistance, the other frictions are minor compared to air resistance at higher speeds.

Comment: The conservatism of markets. I am cycling on a recumbent. The only disadvantage is the price. And the price is higher because the series are much smaller.

Comment: I’m no expert but I’ve been told that recumbents would win road races if they were allowed. So to some extent, it is competition rules that keep new designs from gaining traction.

Comment: Right. I get that air resistance is a huge factor. As is, to a lesser extent, weight. And I get that recumbents reduce this. I'm more interested in the mechanics. The driving efficiency too. Is there something special about two wheels and two cogs that is optimal. Why? Why not?

Comment: @AdrianHoward given a set cross section or even a set friction (air resistance included), are there any optimisations to the [two wheels, triangle frame, foot power through two cogs] archetype that could be improved upon from a mechanics point of view (not simply weight reduction)? If not, why not?

I'm looking at the difference between a penny farthing and a "normal" shaped frame and wondering why there have only been incremental changes for >100 years. Are there no conceptual quantum shifts possible?

Comment: @Turkeyphant: You should see the eta by Aerovelo, they did not have this 100 years ago http://www.aerovelo.com/eta-speedbike

Comment: @AdrianHoward thanks that's interesting. But I guess there's no mechanical trickery that's better than two wheels and two cogs in that case. No clever means of generating rotational motion and nothing better that as few round objects touching the ground as possible? I guess there also haven't been huge progressions in aviation (helicopter/flapping to bi-plane to swept wing to bidirectional) or hull design (monohull to multihull to SWATH).

Answer (score 1):

I would say the principal factors in bicycle design (other than that a bike can only have two wheels) are low mass, high strength - to-mass ratio, position of center of mass when the rider is included, and the ergonomic requirements of a human rider.    All those considerations together point to a design that is a simple truss-type structure with handlebars and seat where they usually are.   Evolution of structural materials and manufacturing methods has changed the landscape a fair amount.  With strong enough materials, it is now possible to make step-through bikes that would be stronger if made the traditional "boy's bike" way, but are strong enough in the step-through configuration to serve their purpose.  Those step-through designs are better in the sense that they take their riders' ergonomics into account a bit better.

Possibly the best bottom line is that "optimum design" depends on how "optimum" is defined: on constraints and on a single value that somehow combines all the quality factors.  Because there are multiple ways to define "optimum" for a bike design,  it can only be fair to say that a given optimal design is optimal for a given purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Racing bikes are continually being developed but, UCI,  the governing body have applied restrictions for world records and in professional racing relating to body position and weight.

The article [hour record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hour_record#1990s:_non-traditional_riding_positions) gives more details about this as does the article [racing bike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racing_bicycle).

You will note that aerodynamic efficiency is extremely important an example being spoked wheels being replaced by disc wheels in some cases as described in the article [cylcle wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_wheel).

Comment: " I'm not interested in UCI rules rather theoretical limits".

Comment: @Turkeyphant I understand that you do not want to know about the UCI rules however the examples I have given do include indications of how bike design can be improved but also that the type of “optimal” bike will depend on the use to which the bike is to be put. So, as asked, there is no definitive answer to your question. Is it speed, acceleration, efficiency, stability, etc that you are after?